# Python Variable Amount Of Input

Tags: python, dictionary, input, graph, collections

I'm working on a program that determines whether a graph is strongly connected.

I am reading standard input on a sequence of lines.

The lines have two or three whitespace-delimited tokens, the name of the source and destination vertices, and an optional decimal edge weight.

Input might look like this:

```
'''
Houston Washington        1000
Vancouver Houston 300
Dallas Sacramento          800
Miami           Ames 2000
SanFrancisco LosAngeles
ORD PVD 1000
'''
```

How can I read in this input and add it to my graph?
I believe I will be using a collection like this:

```
flights = collections.defaultdict(dict)
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you show some code that would have written to do it.

Comment: @yeniv If I were to manually insert it within my code it would look like this: `flights['Washington']['Houston'] = 800` or `flights['Houston']['Atlanta'] = 500`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `d` as your data, you can use split your line with '\n' in it and then strip trailing white space and find the last occurrence of . With that you can slice your string to get the name and the number associated with it.

Here I've stored the data to a dictionary. You can modify it according to your requirement!

Use regular expression modules `re.sub` to remove the extra spaces.

```
>>> import re
>>> d
'\nHouston Washington        1000\nVancouver Houston 300\nDallas Sacramento          800\nMiami           Ames 2000\nSanFrancisco LosAngeles\nORD PVD 1000\n'
>>>[{'Name':re.sub(r' +',' ',each[:each.strip().rfind(' ')]).strip(),'Flight Number':each[each.strip().rfind(' '):].strip()} for each in filter(None,d.split('\n'))]
[{'Flight Number': '1000', 'Name': 'Houston Washington'}, {'Flight Number': '300', 'Name': 'Vancouver Houston'}, {'Flight Number': '800', 'Name': 'Dallas Sacramento'}, {'Flight Number': '2000', 'Name': 'Miami Ames'}, {'Flight Number': 'LosAngeles', 'Name': 'SanFrancisco'}, {'Flight Number': '1000', 'Name': 'ORD PVD'}]
```

**Edit:**

To match your flights dict,

```
>>> flights={'Houston':{'Washington':''},'Vancouver':{'Houston':''}} #sample dict
>>> for each in filter(None,d.split('\n')):
...     flights[each.split()[0]][each.split()[1]]=each.split()[2]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I was looking more along the lines of this: If I were to manually insert it within my code it would look like this: `flights['Washington']['Houston'] = 800` or `flights['Houston']['Atlanta'] = 500` How might I adjust your code to fit this?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I am getting an error now that says 'd' is not defined. I would like to be able to read from Standard Input so someone could enter different amounts of input. How can I fix this error?

Comment: `import sys
d = sys.stdin.read()
flights = {}
for each in filter(None, d.split('\n')):
    flights[each.split()[0]][each.split()[1]] = each.split()[2]`                      And my error now is: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/program12.py", line 5, in <module>
    flights[each.split()[0]][each.split()[1]] = each.split()[2]
KeyError: 'Houston'`